# How to graph "before and after" measures using ggplot with connecting lines and subsets?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I’m totally new to ggplot, relatively fresh with R and want to make a smashing ”before-and-after” scatterplot with connecting lines to illustrate the movement in percentages of different subgroups before and after a special training initiative. I’ve tried some options, but have yet to:

- show each individual observation separately (now same values are overlapping)
- connect the related before and after measures (x=0 and X=1) with lines to more clearly illustrate the direction of variation
- subset the data along class and id using shape and colors

How can I best create a scatter plot using ggplot (or other) fulfilling the above demands?

## Main alternative: geom_point()

Here is some sample data and example code using genom_point

```
    x <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) # 0=before, 1=after
    y <- c(45,30,10,40,10,NA,30,80,80,NA,95,NA,90,NA,90,70,10,80,98,95) # percentage of ”feelings of peace"
    class <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1) # 0=multiple days 1=one day
    id <- c(1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,6,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,6) # id = per individual

    df <- data.frame(x,y,class,id)

    ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y), fill=id, shape=class) + geom_point()
```

[image: Click here for example image based on geom_point()]

## Alternative: scale_size()

I have explored stat_sum() to summarize the frequencies of overlapping observations, but then not being able to subset using colors and shapes due to overlap.

```
    ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
      stat_sum()
```

[image: Click here for example image based on scale_size()]

## Alternative: geom_dotplot()

I have also explored geom_dotplot() to clarify the overlapping observations that arise from using  genom_point() as I do in the example below, however I have yet to understand how to combine the before and after measures into the same plot.

```
    df1 <- df[1:10,] # data before
    df2 <- df[11:20,] # data after

    p1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
      geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center",stackratio=2,
           binwidth=(1/0.3))

    p2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
      geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center",stackratio=2,
           binwidth=(1/0.3))

    grid.arrange(p1,p2, nrow=1) # GridExtra package
```

[image: Click here for example image based on geom_dotplot()]

Comment: There are points/people with multiple values at a specific time (ie, two `id`s of '1' at time zero).  Is this intentional

Comment: I think it would be best to figure out what type of chart you want first, and then people can help you build it. This is a situation where a slopegraph would probably work well, and is easy to implement in ggplot

Comment: @wibeasley Yes, this is intentional and I will be subsetting on this parameter later. Thanks for pointing this unclarity out!

Comment: @camille Thank you generous genius! I have completely forgotten about slopegraphs and I think you're totally right that this is were I should be with the kind of data I have. Will explore further and let you all know how it goes. Until then, thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or maybe it is better to summarize data by `x`, `id`, `class` as `mean`/`median` of `y`, filter out `id`s producing `NA`s (e.g. `id`s 3 and 6), and connect the points by lines? So in case if you don't really need to show variability for some `id`s (which could be true if the plot only illustrates tendencies) you can do it this way:

```
library(ggplot)
library(dplyr)
#library(ggthemes)

df <- df %>%
  group_by(x, id, class) %>%
  summarize(y = median(y, na.rm = T)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    id = factor(id),
    x = factor(x, labels = c("before", "after")),
    class = factor(class, labels = c("one day", "multiple days")),
    ) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(nas = any(is.na(y))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(!nas) %>%
  select(-nas)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, col = id, group = id)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = class)) +
  geom_line(show.legend = F) +
  #theme_few() +
  #theme(legend.position = "none") +
  ylab("Feelings of peace, %") +
  xlab("")
```

[image: lines]

Comment: Thank you so much @utubun for this suggestion and code! I have now tried this approach and it is indeed useful for illustrating tendencies, which I am also interested in as a first start. Together with slopegraphs, as suggested above in the comments by camille I feel like I will be able to illustrate the things I want to illustrate so thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution for you.

First - to get the color and shapes determined by variables, you need to put these into the `aes` function.  I turned several into factors, so the `labs` function fixes the labels so they don't appear as "factor(x)" but just "x".

To address multiple points, one solution is to use `geom_smooth` with `method = "lm"`.  This plots the regression line, instead of connecting all the dots.
The option `se = FALSE` prevents confidence intervals from being plotted - I don't think they add a lot to your plot, but play with it.
Connecting the dots is done by `geom_line` - feel free to try that as well.

Within `geom_point`, the option `position = position_jitter(width = .1)` adds random noise to the x-axis so points do not overlap.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(x), y=y, color=factor(id), shape=factor(class), group = id)) + 
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = .1)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se = FALSE) + 
  labs(
    x = "x",
    color = "ID",
    shape = 'Class'
  )
```